# Python with Ubuntu: Renaming image file keeps old thumbnail

Tags: python

I have a list of directories in my current working directory. In each directory, there are a set of .bmp image files. The image files are originally named randomly. I would like to rename the image files in order, i.e. 1.bmp, 2.bmp, 3.bmp. Here is my code:

```
import os

paths = os.walk('.')
next(paths)

for root, dirs, files in paths:
    image_num = 1
    for old_file in files:
        new_path = os.path.join(root, str(image_num) + '.bmp')
        old_path = os.path.join(root, old_file)
        os.rename(old_path, new_path)
        image_num = image_num + 1
```

The renaming seemed to work fine. However, on closer inspection, I have noticed that the thumbnails for the image files when browsing the directory, no longer correspond to the actual image when it is viewed in Image Viewer, whereas the thumbnails were originally correct. The new thumbnail for an image file now corresponds to one of the other original images - but the "mix up" appears random. I cannot see why this would happen given that all I am doing is renaming a file, without modifying the EXIF data.

Has anybody had any experience with this problem?

Comment: This is probably a nautilus feature and not really related to `python`.  See also http://askubuntu.com/a/211855 for info on where the thumbnails are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if this might still help, but according to the [freedesktop Thumbnail specification](http://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html) Thumbnails are updated based on the modification time (Section 7) of the image, so if your code does not update this field it might cause nautilus to think your image hasn't changed since the last time it saved the Thumbnail in the cache.